# Creating a new maven project guide

Tags: java, maven, vaadin7

I'm about to create a new maven project and came across this interesting guide https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20component
Now, I have a couple of question about getting this to work with a maven project as there seem to be some differences in the way things are handled.

1. When I create a maven project I don't get the same structure described at the end of the article:

   ```
   com.example.mycomponent
      MyComponent.java
      MyComponentWidgetset.gwt.xml
   com.example.mycomponent.client
      MyComponentConnector.java
      MyComponentWidget.java
   ```

   Is that normal? Does it mean that I have to modify my structure in maven?
2. They don't seem to be talking about the pom.xml file but web.xml, are they the same thing?

Generally speaking, what I wanted to do was to create a new maven project and follow this tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin and Maven are two different things.

Vaadin is a Java framework for building modern web applications, which you can then import in the Maven project via the POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Optional for extending client-side See: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/clientside.html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
-->

<!-- Optional for optimizing client-side widgets See: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/mobile.optimization.html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Optional push support for communication See: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.6</version>
</dependency>
-->
```

Source https://vaadin.com/maven#dependencies

To then create a Vaadin project with Maven, check this [tutorial](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-maven.html)

> Maven’s primary goal is to allow a developer to comprehend the
>   complete state of a development effort in the shortest period of time.
>   In order to attain this goal there are several areas of concern that
>   Maven attempts to deal with:
>
> 1. Making the build process easy
> 2. Providing a uniform build system
> 3. Providing quality project information
> 4. Providing guidelines for best practices development
> 5. Allowing transparent migration to new features
>
> Source: [maven](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html)

Comment: thanks, well I usually create maven projects, so perhaps my question should have been, can I use that guide with a maven project?

Comment: @antobbo I dont think so, check the : https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/getting-started/getting-started-maven.html link, This one i put in the Answer aswell

Answer (score 0):

The provided link is not describing about Maven project it's just how to do in java. But that dosen't mean you cannot use Maven.

In maven the project structure will be as follows for a web application

```
Project Root
    |
    +-pom.xml
    +-src
       +-main
          +-java
          +-resources
          +-webapp
              +-WEB-INF
                   +-web.xml
```

- `pom.xml` is where you define the project details like group id,
  artifact id and version along with project dependencies (in your case
  Vaadin dependencies).
- `src\main\java` folder will have your java
  files.
- `src\main\resources` folder will have non java files those you
  need in the classpath.
- `src\main\webapp` folder will have the web
  resources like html, css javascript etc along with `WEB-INF` folder.

So your project structure will be

```
Project Root
    |
    +-pom.xml
    +-src
       +-main
          +-java
          |   +-com
          |      +-example
          |          +-mycomponent
          |                 +-MyComponent.java
          |                 +-client
          |                     +-MyComponentConnector.java
          |                     +-MyComponentWidget.java
          +-resources
          |     +-com
          |        +-example
          |             +-mycomponent
          |                   +MyComponentWidgetset.gwt.xml
          +-webapp
              +-WEB-INF
                   +-web.xml
```

For your question on is pom.xml and web.xml is same? it's not [pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) is for maven project object model and the [web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml) is web deployment descriptor.

Comment: OK cool, so it's possible to "translate" (for the lack of a better word) that project into a maven one, cool, thanks I will give it a go